# Can I accrue miles from award ticket awarded from another airlines

Tags: loyalty-programs, miles-and-more, ana

I have mileage cards from both ANA and Lufthansa, both Star Alliance members.

If I buy an award Lufthansa flight ticket with miles from ANA card, do I earn miles on my Lufthansa card for that flight?

Comment: In short: no!   .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Points/miles are awarded based on the fare class flown.  And award tickets have their own fare classes.  It doesn't matter whose points/miles you used, the ticket you fly on will have an award fare class code attached.  And award fare classes do not earn points/miles in any program I have ever heard of.

Comment: Yes, this is almost always correct. The only exception I can think of is that some credit cards allow you to use the points you earn with the credit card company to buy revenue fares, for which you do earn miles with the airline. These are usually a poor value, though.

Comment: @reirab While they may be poor value, I did once (about 10 years ago) bought an award flight with Hilton HHonour points for London-Philadelphia return trip and did get BA miles for the trip.

Comment: @AleksG That's a good point; I wasn't thinking about those. The reason I mentioned that it's usually (but not always) a poor value in regards to credit card points is that most of the cards that offer that also allow you to instead transfer the points themselves to the airline and book award flights, which typically have better redemption value.

Comment: @reirab Ah, I see.  Well, with Hilton, I could transfer, but transfer worked out 5-for-1 (i.e. 100K points for 20K miles).  Return trip LHR-PHL was 100K hilton points or 30K miles.

Comment: @AleksG Yeah, with the exception of Starwood, hotel points usually don't have great transfer rates. Cards are commonly 1-to-1 (and occasionally even better,) though.

Comment: @reirab - Credit card rewards programs are totally different than airline rewards programs.  It is an apples and watermelons comparison.  The OPs question was about frequent flyer awards.

Answer (score 7):

You know you can't, come now. An airline will grant you miles as a form of gratitude for giving money with the. All sorts of other shenanigans (non-revenue flights, industry discounts, you are the chairman of Port Authority so United runs a flight into your weekend home essentially just for you and whatever else) do not qualify. [Lufthansa's policy](https://www.miles-and-more.com/online/portal/mam/ca/earn/flight/offer?nodeid=2507840&l=en):

> In general, miles cannot be earned on flight award tickets and on travel-industry discounted tickets 
>   (e.g. ID, AD).

Also here's [AA](https://www.aa.com/i18n/aadvantage-program/terms-and-conditions.jsp):

> You may accrue mileage only for purchased, eligible, published-fare tickets

Comment: Regarding the Port Authority crack: David Samson did pressure United into running the EWR-CAE flights. But as far as I've heard, once in operation, they were ordinary scheduled commercial flights and Samson paid for his tickets.  So presumably he earned miles just like any other passenger.

Comment: Well Jeff $mi$ek resigned over those flights and they only ran once a week: Thursday afternoons (Newark -> Columbia) and Monday mornings (Columbia -> Newark) and was cancelled very soon after the chairman resigned. In 2012, it had a spectacular 29.84% load factor. If the airline did this, I'd be surprised if they made him pay for his ticket...

Comment: Operating the flight at a loss for the convenience of a politician is arguably legal, albeit awful. Giving him free tickets on terms not available to the public tends towards bribery.

Comment: @ZachLipton: Samson did plead guilty to bribery specifically for accepting the scheduling of the flight as a "thing of value" in order to be "influenced and rewarded" in connection with his official business.  Had he also accepted free tickets, that would have been an even more blatant violation, but as far as I know, he was never charged with such a count.  So I conclude the government didn't have evidence to show he got the tickets for free, meaning he probably paid for them.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah thanks. I didn't realize that was the crux of the bribery charge. I agree that taking the tickets for free would have been much more obvious and they would have gone after him for that if it happened, though it's functionally the same thing since the tickets were priced far below the point where the route could ever be profitable.